# Make DIV blocks flow into free space

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a block based interface for my portfolio website in which each inlined block represent one of my works and, when clicked, it would expand to double of its size and show more information.

With that set, I started to code it, but I ran into a problem: when a block expand, it always leave a white space in the following line, no matter which css setting I set (I've tried a dozen already), and what I really want is for the white space to be fullfiled with the following items.

It's better explained on the following image:

[image]
This is the actual HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    1
</div>
<div class="block">
    2
</div>
<div class="block big">
    3
</div>
<div class="block">
    4
</div>
<div class="block">
    5
</div>
<div class="block">
    6
</div>
<div class="block">
    7
</div>
<div class="block">
    8
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.block{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.big{
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

I've already tried to play with float values, but no luck here.

Comment: Something like this: http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/ ?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'd be surprised if you find a pure CSS solution for this. Is that what you're looking for, or would some helping javascript be ok?

Comment: @sachleen no, I want to add content of all sorts inside the blocks afterwards, not just images like a gallery

Comment: @SteveWilkes if there is a solution on js, I would gladly look up to, but I don't want things to get overly complicated (specially for cross-browser compatibility) hehe

Comment: @gustavofritsch with some modifications it should work with any element :)

Comment: @sachleen either way, it's not quite like that... but I found a link to a useful library on your link (http://masonry.desandro.com/). Going to give that a try now

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the Masonry js library was able to do the trick (also came with a nice set of well documented features and methods) even though it does not uses pure CSS.

Here is the link: http://masonry.desandro.com